# Upgrading user to superuser giving error through bash

Tags: bash, xubuntu, azure

I have Ubuntu VM on Azure. I am installing OpenEdx on Azure. I am using bash for running commands.
I have ssh to VM. I want to upgrade a user to super user.Below is the command i am asked to follow:

```
sudo su -s /bin/bash edxapp> cd>/edx/bin/python.edxapp /edx/bin/manage.edxapp lms manage_user staff staff@example.com --staff --superuser --settings=aws
```

I have updated it with proper usename and email. I also replaced aws with Azure since I am working on Azure and not on aws.Below is my command.

```
sudo su -s /bin/bash edxapp> cd> /edx/bin/python.edxapp /edx/bin/manage.edxapp lms manage_user Chandrashekhar chandrashekhar.patil@millionlights.in --staff--superuser --settings=azure
```

But it is giving error as permission denied.Can anybody tell me what is going wrong in this command? I have tried removing content after email address also. But not executing. Please let me know. Please write if you have any questions.

Comment: Have your created a superuser ("root") password on your Ubuntu?  Otherwise, why not just add the user to "sudoers" group?

Comment: While creating Ubuntu VM on Azure, I set one password to that VM. Is it the "root" password? Please tell me how can i proceed to create user to superuser.